# Counting occurrences in data-frame without aggregating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to count the number of occurrences in a data frame without aggregating or deleting the duplicated value.

this is what I have tried thus far:
    df['counts']=df.no_.value_counts()
    df['counts']=df.groupby(no_).count()

```
key1 key2  
a  one         
a  two         
b  one         
b  two         
a  one         
c  two
```

I would like the result to look like this, the count column need only reflect the column in question (in this case key1)

```
key1 key2 count(key1)
a  one  3
a  two  3      
b  one  2       
b  two  2      
a  one  3       
c  two  1
```

Comment: df['count']=df.groupby('key1').key2.transform('count')

Comment: Ideally, I would only like to include 1 column as I have 16